# selector function not called when adding list of image views with tap gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, memory, uiscrollview

I have trouble with creating list of ImageViews with tap gesture. When I create gesture, selector function is not called. When I create only one imageView function is called. Any idea why? It is all subview of a large scroll view.

This is my code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self     action:@selector(imageTaped:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
for(int k=0;k<MyList.count;k++){
    for(int i=0;i<listSize;i++){
        UIImageView *clickForDetail =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*HELLO_WIDTH,k*LIST_ROW_HEIGH ,HELLO_WIDTH, LIST_ROW_HEIGH)];
        clickForDetail.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        clickForDetail.tag = tag;
        clickForDetail.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [clickForDetail addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

        [myScroll addSubview:clickForDetail];
        tag++;
    }
}
```

and selector function:

```
-(void)imageTaped: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"single Tap on imageview");
}
```

Is it possible somehow to get tag of a ImageView that is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put different tap gesture for each view object

```
for(int k=0;k<MyList.count;k++){
    for(int i=0;i<listSize;i++){
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self     action:@selector(imageTaped:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        UIImageView *clickForDetail =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*HELLO_WIDTH,k*LIST_ROW_HEIGH ,HELLO_WIDTH, LIST_ROW_HEIGH)];
        clickForDetail.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        clickForDetail.tag = tag;
        clickForDetail.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [clickForDetail addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

        [epgScroll addSubview:clickForDetail];
        tag++;
    }
}


-(void)imageTaped: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"single Tap on imageview");
UIImageView *selectedTextView = (UIImageView *)recognizer.view;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to detect which image view is clicked by its tag?